# What makes a good tag-wiki entry?

Tags: discussion, editing, tagwiki

I've been adding some tag-wiki entries, (e.g. for [memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoir),  [polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglossia), and [linguistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics), and [texshop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texshop)).  I'm happy to add more, but I'm wondering whether what I've done matches what people have in mind for a tag-wiki entry.  Clearly there are different requirements for an entry on a topic (like the [linguistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) entry) and an entry for a package like the [memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoir) and [polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglossia) entries.

Since the entries don't get any feedback (other than a mod approving them) it's hard to know if this work is useful or elicits a kind of "well it's not very good but better than no entry at all" response.

So what makes a good tag-wiki entry? (Also, is there a way to make the examples listed appear in the html as an actual tag would?)

Comment: You can use `[tag:tagname]` to link to a tag in markdown.

Comment: @Caramdir Thanks.  That was was I was looking for. (Although that doesn't seem to do the css magic of putting up the black box with the exceprt text and the links to the tag-wiki entry itself.)

Comment: That doesn't work on meta (but works in tag wikis).

Comment: @Caramdir, @Alan: With my browser settings, the second line starts with the "," after "{linguistics}". Seems to be a rendering bug; I've [filed a bug report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/80483/possible-bug-punctuation-after-inline-tags).

Answer (score 9):

Suggestions for a good tag wiki:

- A brief introduction
- Further explanation
- Links to related packages and classes
- What the tag is not about: links to tags which might be a better choice in some circumstances
- A link-list of closely related, but more specific tags, which might be a good specific choice
- Links to highly voted questions resp. answers on the site, like a tag FAQ

Comment: great list! do note that the tag faq is generated automatically by inferring cross-linked posts, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/faq -- this only tends to work well on popular tags simply due to question volume

Comment: Also note that special formatting, like backticks and tag links do not work in the excerpt.

Comment: @Stefan Points 4 and 5 are very helpful; thanks.  Point 2 is a tad vague :-)  W.r.t. related packages and classes, I assume that makes sense for a topic tag as opposed to a package tag?  Or should e.g. the `memoir` tag also point to KOMA (and vice versa)?  Maybe that's too extreme a case.  Should the `longtable` tag also point to `supertabular`?

Comment: @Martin Actually my question about formatting was in this question (or in the tag-wki entry itself: is there a way in markdown to identify something as a tag so that it does the css magic that happens when you hover over a tag link?)

Comment: @Alan: Not that I know of. I figured I should mention this, since I've seen a few tag wikis just today in which formatting has been used, and when hovering it doesn't look very nice.

Comment: @Alan: Links to related packages and topics are good, even if they are "competitors" - good to point to alternatives. A tag wiki could be a small knowledge base to a topic, even if a certain package causes the topic. Related information is contained in the right sidebar or in the automatic faq, as Jeff said, nevertheless a manual choice might be a good addition.