# 'Write a nice description for a blank tag' marathon

Tags: discussion, tagwiki, chat

Friends, I'd like to suggest something similar to the **['answer the unanswered' session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/1363495/history)**: a **'write a nice description for a blank tag' marathon** (*I could not think of a fancy name as cool as the other*).

Taken from the **[Tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags)** page:

> A **tag** is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

They are *really* useful when searching for specific topics or even to better classify our own questions.

Unfortunately, a bunch of those tags have *no description at all*. When you add a tag to a question, a short description pops up to help us decide whether this tag is relevant to our question or not. With no description, such harmless tag can mislead us to use it instead of a better one, thus requiring a possible peer retagging process.

[image: Yay tags!]
[image: Yay tags again!]

IMHO even the self-explanatory tags deserve a description. I use to fail at tagging my own questions (*Thankfully Caramdir, lockstep and Seamus always save me*).

This idea is probably low priority, since things work pretty well in here. But I think we could benefit from filling up our empty/blank tags.

Comment: Sorry, I could not resist retagging this :)

Comment: Also, I like this idea. I try to add tag wikis now any then, but often I don't really know a good definition. Having a session where this can be discussed quickly could be quite useful.

Comment: @Caramdir: LOL, it made my day! `=)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a good idea. In a chat session we can speak about how to make good tag wikis, collect new ideas regarding this, learn more about it during discussion and perhaps directly create some.

Here's a link for a start:

- [What makes a good tag-wiki entry?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/what-makes-a-good-tag-wiki-entry)

And since you looked for a fancy name, here's one matching the other sessions:

> Describe the undescribed!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Stefan! BTW that fancy name is awesome (specially if said with a Stephen King's voice)! `=P`

Answer (score 3):

To report an interim result: As of now, every entry on the first *two* "Tags" pages features a tag wiki excerpt. The highest-scoring tag without wiki excerpt is now [algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) (63 questions).