# Discussion about tag-wiki policies

Tags: discussion, tagwiki

I'm intending this question to be a place for discussion about tag-wiki policies, which after the discussion can be included in [What makes a good tag-wiki entry?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/what-makes-a-good-tag-wiki-entry). This way, that question can be kept clean and a bit FAQ-like. If you think this isn't the best discussion format, please make suggestions; I just didn't feel like asking a question on each single question was the right thing.

So here are some questions I have:

---

### 1. Markdown / backticks

Markdown isn't allowed in tag wiki excerpts ([mod statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218), [more meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62266/tag-box-on-top-of-questions-page-doesnt-show-markdown-backticks)/[questions on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62614/tag-wiki-summary-does-not-allow-markup)/[this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63656/allow-back-quote-code-formatting-syntax-in-tag-wiki-excerpt)).

I've seen some tag wiki excerpts that still contain backticks (`) to indicate code, e.g. [titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles), which imho doesn't look good, in particular considering that it's pretty clear what's code and what isn't. The same applies to question titles, and I think we discourage use of backticks in question titles. Hence:

Should backticks be used in tag wiki excerpts? I say: no.

P.S.: There's [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) and [markup](/questions/tagged/markup). What's the difference?

---

### 2. Duplicate excerpt in "big" tag wiki?

Do an excerpt and the "big" tag wiki entry complement each other or are the independent from each other? I.e., should the "big" tag wiki reduplicate all the information given in the excerpt? If there's no "big" entry, should the excerpt just be copied there?

Since the "big" entry never appears on its own afaik, I don't think this is necessary. It happens frequently, though, e.g. in [small-caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-caps).

---

### 3. Taking package descriptions from ctan.org

When I started the [titling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titling) tag wiki, I looked up http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling and found a good and concise description of the package. Thus, I copied it and added "(quoted from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling)". Is this ok? I just figured "Why make up a new description if the package author, who probably knows the package best, has already provided such a great description?". [etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etoolbox) used the CTAN description as well and even used blockquote markup.

Comment: On the PS: **markup** is generic, **markdown** is particular.  Less concisely, "markup" refers to a syntax of "marking up" source for processing.  "Markdown" is a specific type of this.

Answer (score 5):

I'll give it a shot and answer the questions.

## 1.

Don't use back ticks in tag wiki excerpts.

## 2.

The status quo has changed since the creation of this question: Now, the excerpt is not shown by default on the tag wiki page. Hence, it'd be good if the tag wiki contained the information given in the excerpt as well. After all, that's what an excerpt is: a condensed selection of information.

## 3.

Yes, it's ok to copy package descriptions from CTAN, just make it clear what's quoted and from where.