# Font size and "show excerpt" link in tag wiki pages

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, tagwiki, fonts

These are technically two different issues, but they're not too big of a deal so I'm putting them in the same question.

Status quo:

[image: braces tag wiki]

## 1. Size of *About {braces}*

Can the font size of *{braces}* be adapted to be the same as the one of *About*?

## 2. Position of *show excerpt* link.

It seems to be new to me that the tag wiki excerpt is not shown by default. This is quite interesting because it implies that the (long) tag wiki should contain all the information given in the excerpt, partially answering [Discussion about tag-wiki policies](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/4012). But that's just a side comment, I'd actually like to suggest to **move the *show excerpt* to the place where the excerpt is going to be shown**, i.e. in between *About {braces}*  and *These are characters ...*. It just seems more natural and it would de-clutter the three-link area down there, in which it is kind of hard to tell on the first glance where one link ends and where the next one starts.