# Who designs the best tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tagwiki, contests

Tags are a map of our site. Tag description pages can be like small home pages, including information, internal links and links to helpful external resources. And they can be written with markdown syntax.

Many users alread helped in writing wiki entries for the most used tags. What is the most impressive tag wiki?

I encourage you to

- design a great tag wiki page and post the link here
- post the tag for which you already created a very nice wiki page
- participate here also if you contributed a substantial part to an existing wiki
- at least comment if you know a great wiki page which hasn't been mentioned yet

For example, couldn't [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), the tag for the powerful, feature-rich, comprehensive TikZ package much better? Useful reading:

- [What makes a good tag-wiki entry?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/what-makes-a-good-tag-wiki-entry)
- [Redesigned Tags Page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)

This question looks for some outstanding, excellent tag wikis. The best tag wiki page, posted here during the next week, may get a prominent place in a presentation about this site, for example in [talks at conferences](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/possible-conference-speaking-sponsorships-2011), publications and on our [blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: Here's an [inspirational tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) for Scala on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And just so I don't get accused of solely tooting my own horn :-), the [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) tag is really good too.

Comment: Examples with pictures, great!

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly pleased with the [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex) tag wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Today I extended the [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) tag wiki by links to internal and external resources such as packages, tutorials, special related tags and example questions.

Answer (score 2):

The [linguistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) tag also reasonably comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered the tag wikis (they're somewhat hidden) and today created, among other things, a wiki for [letterspacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letterspacing). *Then* I stumbled across this thread and started wondering if what I wrote really meets the standards of a decent tag wiki entry. Compared to the tags mentioned here, my article looks pretty verbose, even though I don't think it contains a lot more than the basics of what people should know about its subject. To be honest, I even think a lot more could be added, but then again, I know this is not Wikipedia -- what do you think?

Comment: First of all I think this is a new question, not an an answer. But second I am not sure, if this as a new question would not be too localized. I guess you should have asked this in chat.