# tikz drawing requests following an image

Tags: discussion

In reference to `tikz`, I have seen varius questions that you know an image and pay directly `tikz` code that draws such image.

For someone like me without much experience in `tikz` I see it as something that honors this place, however, I see it as something vague; since it directly asks for the code to clone the image instead of doing it yourself and asking more specific questions about the drawing process.

So my question, as someone new to **Tex-LaTeX Stack Exchange** is:

Is it legitimate to ask these questions? Is it well seen in this place?

Comment: related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/dealing-with-just-do-it-for-me-questions and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7926/36296

Comment: It is not legitimate but trying to avoid it is fighting a losing battle.

Comment: It's a perennial problem, and since there will always be people willing to answer them it will never go away. So if it bothers you, just ignore the questions entirely, which is what many of us do.